# Дизайн и привилегии

Tags: обсуждение

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/1#comment-184588

> Our privilege reputation thresholds haven't increased yet. They'll increase at the same time we get a custom site design.

И на metaSE встречал что-то про дизайн с привилегиями.

А почему у нас и нового дизайна не было, и уровни для привилегий выросли сразу после аттестации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это несколько иной случай, потому что у сайта Stack Overflow дизайн уже есть. Он распространяется и на локализованные сайты, с небольшим добавлением в логотипе и изменением фона иконки. Для сравнения: [pt.SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [ja.SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [es.SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).